# New Open Graph - important life moments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Will I be able to display a user's Timeline highlights (important life moments) with my Open Graph App?

Will this be possible with the new changes? I'm looking for some kind of API for the Timeline highlights.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to get the user's aggregations or timeline highlights via the API, but you will be able to read back any actions the user published into the Graph using your application.

There will soon be the ability for you to request access to other actions the user performed in other apps, and you can then make use of this data, but this will be the raw actions, not aggregations of them.

Comment: Thank You @SimonCross. so only actions, i see. but if the user have post in their timeline info about travel, graduation, work can i still get that info via API?